# Bash find exclude caseinsenstive

Tags: bash, find

I am using the below to find files with matching extensions that I need. however, I can't seem to get it to exclude certain keywords I want and also make sure keywords case insenstive...

```
find . -type f \(  -name \*.avi -o -name \*.mkv -o -name \*.mp4 -o -name \*.VOB \)
```

any kind of help I can get on this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

case insensitive: use `-iname` instead of `-name`.

Comment: thank you! how about excluding certain keywords from the search? like mp3?

Comment: try with a ! with the iname , eg : find -type f -a ! -iname "INPUT*"

Comment: you can add parenthesis : `\( ......  \)` (backslach before them so the shell doesn't take them for "launch a subshell here"), to help prioritize the things in the right evaluation order